# Aggregate dataframe by condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have the following DataFrame in R:

```
 Y       ...    Price      Year           Quantity      Country    
010190   ...   4781       2021               4           Germany    
010190   ...   367        2021               3           Germany 
010190   ...   4781       2021               6           France    
010190   ...   250        2021               3           France    
020190   ...   690        2021               NA          USA        
020190   ...   10         2021               6           USA  
......         ...         ....              ..          ...   
217834  ...    56        2021                3           USA        
217834 ...     567       2021                9           USA
```

As you see the numbers in **Y** column startin with 01.., 02..., 21... I want to aggregate such kind of rows from 6 digit to 2 digit by considering different categorical column (e.g. **Country** and **Year**) and sum numerical columns like **Quantity** and **Price**. Also I want to take into account rows with NAs during caclulation. So, in the end I want such kind of output:

```
 Y     Price      Year          Quantity   Country
01     5148       2021           7         Germany
01     5031       2021           9          USA
02     700        2021           6          USA
..     ....       ...           ....        ...      
21     623        2021           12         USA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update: request:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Y = substr(Y, 1, 2)) %>% 
  group_by(Y, Year, Country) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(Price, Quantity), ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

We could use `substr` to get the first two characters from `Y` and `group_by` and `summarise()` with `sum()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Y = substr(Y, 1, 2)) %>% 
  group_by(Y, Year, Country) %>% 
  summarise(Price = sum(Price, na.rm = TRUE),
            Quantity = sum(Quantity, na.rm = TRUE)
            )
```

```
  Y      Year Country Price Quantity
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1 01     2021 France   5031        9
2 01     2021 Germany  5148        7
3 02     2021 USA       700        6
4 21     2021 USA       623       12
```

Comment: is it possible to avoid coding numerical variables one by one and use something like c("Price", "Quantity"?

Comment: Yes . Please see my update. We can do this with `across`

Comment: After using na.rm = TRUE, NAs are converted as 0 in the output. is it possible to do this calculation and keep NAs in the output?

Comment: You mean `na.rm = FALSE`?

Comment: If I na.rm = FALSE and one of the row has NA, column is not summed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` and `summarize` from `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Y = sprintf(as.numeric(factor(Y, unique(Y))), fmt = '%02d')) %>%
  group_by(Y, Year, Country) %>%
  summarize(across(where(is.numeric), sum))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#> # Groups:   Y, Year [3]
#>    Y      Year Country Price Quantity
#>    <chr> <int> <chr>   <int>    <int>
#>  1 01     2021 France   5031        9
#>  2 01     2021 Germany  5148        7
#>  3 02     2021 USA       700       NA
```

Comment: That's not what I asked for. Look Y column of output, it must be 2 digits not 6 or 5!

Comment: @Underwood see my update

Comment: Thanks. After using na.rm = TRUE, NAs are converted as 0 in the output. is it possible to do this calculation and keep NAs in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` and the `substr`ing of `Y`.

```
aggregate(cbind(Quantity, Price) ~ Y + Year + Country, 
          transform(dat, Y=substr(Y, 1, 2)), sum)
#    Y Year Country Quantity Price
# 1 10 2021  France        9  5031
# 2 10 2021 Germany        7  5148
# 3 20 2021     USA        7   700
# 4 21 2021     USA       12   623
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Y = c(10190L, 10190L, 10190L, 10190L, 20190L, 
20190L, 217834L, 217834L), foo = c("...", "...", "...", "...", 
"...", "...", "...", "..."), Price = c(4781L, 367L, 4781L, 250L, 
690L, 10L, 56L, 567L), Year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L), model = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Tesla", 
"Tesla"), Quantity = c(4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 9L), Country = c("Germany", 
"Germany", "France", "France", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Error in substr(Y, 1, 2) : object 'Y' not found

Comment: @Underwood Code works for example data, adapt it to your data which probably has no `Y` column or it's named differently.